# Android - Adjust button height by checkbox height?

Tags: android, view, size

I've got a `ListView`, one row of which contains `Button`, `CheckBox` and multiline `TextView`. The xml layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="fill_parent"
               android:layout_centerVertical="true">

    <Button android:id="@+id/open"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:src="@drawable/play"
              android:text="Play"
              android:layout_centerVertical="true"
           />

    <CheckBox android:id="@+id/check"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_centerVertical="true"
             android:layout_toRightOf="@id/open"
           />

    <TextView android:text="@+id/label"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:id="@+id/label"
             android:textSize="16px"
             android:layout_toRightOf="@id/check"
             android:paddingLeft="4px"
           />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Screenshot of `ListView`:

[image: Screenshot of Listview]

How  can I  adjust the button height with checkbox height?

Comment: whats your XML for Start Download button?

Comment: The start download button and listview usually located in some sort of LinearLayout AFIK so probably there's something wrong there with your LinearLayout.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the ALIGN_TOP and ALIGN_BOTTOM properties of relative layout. You can align the top and bottom of your button to the top and bottom of the check box.

Answer (score 0):

You can set custom style to the button with lower padding values then the default one.
You can set margin for the button.
You can set a fixed DP value for the buttons height.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

```
<Button android:id="@+id/open"
        ...    
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        ...
        />
```